# How to make Sequelize use singular table names

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an model called User but Sequelize looks for the table USERS whenever I am trying to save in the DB. Does anyone know how to set Sequelize to use singular table names? Thanks.

Comment: `user` is a reserved word, you'll have loads of problems if you really try to create a table with that name.

Comment: `user` is not a reserved word, but a keyword. While you won't encounter a problem using it, it's good to avoid it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 287):

The [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#enforcing-the-table-name-to-be-equal-to-the-model-name) state that you can use the property `freezeTableName`.

Please take a look at this example:

```
var Bar = sequelize.define('Bar', { /* bla */ }, {
  // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps: false,

  // don't delete database entries but set the newly added attribute deletedAt
  // to the current date (when deletion was done). paranoid will only work if
  // timestamps are enabled
  paranoid: true,

  // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
  // so updatedAt will be updated_at
  underscored: true,

  // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
  // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
  // if you don't want that, set the following
  freezeTableName: true,

  // define the table's name
  tableName: 'my_very_custom_table_name'
})
```

Comment: I've updated the link in your question because it was broken, hope you don't mind!

Comment: `freezeTableName: true` is not working in the latest version of sequelize. Any other solution?

Comment: One downside to `freezeTableName` is that it _also_ prevents sqlz from lowercasing table and column names. Which means that later, when you're hand-writing SQL to dig through data, you have to cope with mixed-case names (whatever that means for your dialect). On pg, it means having to use double-quotes around every mixed-case name -- yuk! I wish we could opt-out of pluralization but retain case-folding... `define` has `tableName` option for explicit override.

Comment: use `freezeTableName: true` in addition of `modelName: 'singularName'`

Answer (score 115):

While the accepted answer is correct, you can do this once for all tables rather than having to do it separately for each one. You simply pass in a similar options object into the Sequelize constructor, like so:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

//database wide options
var opts = {
    define: {
        //prevent sequelize from pluralizing table names
        freezeTableName: true
    }
}

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root:123abc@localhost:3306/mydatabase', opts)
```

Now when you define your entities, you don't have to specify `freezeTableName: true`:

```
var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, here is the [link to documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#application-wide-model-options) for those who interested.

Answer (score 18):

You can Do it direct rather than specifying in every table you have define it once
like below

```js
var db_instance = new Sequelize(config.DB.database, config.DB.username, config.DB.password, {
  host: config.DB.host,
  dialect: config.DB.dialect,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: true
  },
  logging: false
});
```

***OR***

You can simply tell Sequelize the name of the table directly as well:

```js
sequelize.define('User', {
  // ... (attributes)
}, {
  tableName: 'Employees'
});
```

You can see both Method in Documentation of sequelize.js

[Doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#enforcing-the-table-name-to-be-equal-to-the-model-name). Of sequelize.js related to `freezeTableName`

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer as it also mentions how to do it for individual tables

Answer (score 8):

If you require to have different model names for singuar and plural definitions you can pass name as a parameter in options of model.

Please take a look at this example:

```
    const People = sequelize.define('people', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
    hooks: {
        beforeCount (options) {
            options.raw = true;
        }
    },
    tableName: 'people',
    name: {
        singular: 'person',
        plural: 'people'
    }
});
```

this will return "person" as an object when a single record is being queried and "people" as an array when we fetch multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Model, Sequelize, DataTypes} from 'sequelize';
import {IUser} from "../model/IUser";


module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  class User extends Model<IUser> implements IUser {

    public email!: string;
    public password!: string;
    static associate(models: any) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  User.init({
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user',
    tableName: 'your_table_name'
  });
  return User;
};
```