# sequelize gives the wrong table name

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I have a database. Where i have a "`user`" table

I am trying to create my first `REST` api using `sequelize`

however when it executes my query i get the following in the console:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `name`, `organization_id`, `type_id`, `join_date` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = '1';
```

as you can see it tries to use a table called `users` however this table does not exists.

Here is some of my code:

Please do tell me if you need more i am not really sure where it goes wrong? :S

```
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    join_date: DataTypes.STRING

}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        retrieveAll: function(onSuccess, onError) {
            User.findAll({}, {raw: true})
                .ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        retrieveById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            User.find({where: {id: user_id}}, {raw: true})
                .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        add: function(onSuccess, onError) {
            var username = this.username;
            var password = this.password;

            var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            shasum.update(password);
            password = shasum.digest('hex');

            User.build({ username: username, password: password })
                .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        updateById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            var id = user_id;
            var username = this.username;
            var password = this.password;

            var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            shasum.update(password);
            password = shasum.digest('hex');

            User.update({ username: username,password: password},{where: {id: id} })
                .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        removeById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            User.destroy({where: {id: user_id}}).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does the "user" table actually already exist in your DB?  And did you create it manually or did Sequelize create it?

Comment: @HeadCode the user table exists in my database and was created manually and already contains loads of data

Comment: I didn't realize this, but "user" looks to be a reserved keyword.  I can't say this is causing you a problem, but  check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114499/how-to-make-sequelize-use-singular-table-names

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to set freezeTableName = true inside your options object.

e.g.

```
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    join_date: DataTypes.STRING

}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    instanceMethods: {
        retrieveAll: function(onSuccess, onError) {
            User.findAll({}, {raw: true})
                .ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        retrieveById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            User.find({where: {id: user_id}}, {raw: true})
                .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        add: function(onSuccess, onError) {
            var username = this.username;
            var password = this.password;

            var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            shasum.update(password);
            password = shasum.digest('hex');

            User.build({ username: username, password: password })
                .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        updateById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            var id = user_id;
            var username = this.username;
            var password = this.password;

            var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            shasum.update(password);
            password = shasum.digest('hex');

            User.update({ username: username,password: password},{where: {id: id} })
                .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        },
        removeById: function(user_id, onSuccess, onError) {
            User.destroy({where: {id: user_id}}).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: WOW ive been so close to solving this i just inserted that line in the wrong place thank you!

Comment: Thanks for pointing us in the right direction, but the actual syntax above is not correct: `freezeTableName = true` should be `freezeTableName: true`

Answer (score -2):

I have not used sequelize before, but reading from their documentation - may be you are missing -

`User.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  // Table created
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Hancock'
  });
});`

i.e. the table creation part...

Thanks

Comment: instead of using the table "user" this just creates a table called "users"