# Sequelize table name change

Tags: sequelize.js

Have renamed a table from `users` to `user` in MySQL database. In `Express` I'm running `Sequelize` and created a schema for the old `users` table. With the table renamed and everything in the code changed from `users` to `user`, `Sequelize` is still looking for a table named specifically `users` even though the table name is updated in the schema.

```
User = db.sequelize.define('user', {
  first_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  last_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
  role: Sequelize.STRING,
  created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
  updated_at: Sequelize.DATE
});
```

Tried running this to overwrite the table with one produced by `Sequelize` and it still created a table named `users`

```
User.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  // Table created
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'test',
    lastName: 'test',
    email: 'test@example.com',
    password: 'password'
  });
});
```

Has anyone else experienced the same? Is there some other configuration I am missing? This is all I did in the first place when creating the first table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Sequelize use singular table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114499/how-to-make-sequelize-use-singular-table-names)

Answer (score 14):

Sequelize pluralizes table name by default, Set `freezeTableName: true` to change this behavior like this.

```
User = db.sequelize.define('user', {
    first_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    last_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    role: Sequelize.STRING,
    created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
    updated_at: Sequelize.DATE
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to nodeJS and spent so much time to identify what was wrong with the sequelize. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Its been years since I've used the Sequelize framework, but I'm pretty sure the framework has a concept of pluralized table names by default. 
From memory, configuration needs to be provided in `create` to prevent this - so in conjunction with your non-pluralized table name, you'd also specify `freezeTableName: true`.

Looks like the docs state this:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

recent sequelize version allows you to do this

```
up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.showAllTables().then(async (tables) => {any function})
```