# When updating Sequelize model, fails and returns different table name than I provided?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm running PostgreSQL 11, and attempting to update one of its table entries using Sequelize.

My NodeJS code:

```
require('env2')('.env');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize=new Sequelize(process.env.database,process.env.username,process.env.password,{
    dialect:'postgres'
});

const Agent=sequelize.define('agent');
updateValues={available:false};
Agent.update(updateValues,{where:{phonenumber:'+18005551212'}}).then(result=>{console.log(result)});
```

The table `agent` has the structure:

```
id primary key serial,
phonenumber varchar(100),
available boolean
```

When I run the NodeJS code, I get this error:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE "agents" SET "updatedAt"='2018-12-27 10:16:54.504 +0
0:00' WHERE "phonenumber" = '+18005551212'
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "agents" does not exist
```

Why is this update failing?  I don't understand why the error is talking about the relation "agents", when I provided the table name as "agent" in `sequelize.define(agent)`.

The update is successful when I use raw SQL as follows:

```
sequelize.query("update agent set available=false where phonenumber='+18005551212'").then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default sequelize creates a table with a plural of its definition name, so when you  do `sequelize.define('agent')` it actually creates a table with name `agents` . If you don't want to change your table name naturally you can use `freezeTableName: true` option in sequelize definition. More can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114499/how-to-make-sequelize-use-singular-table-names) answer. Refer Sequelize configuration [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration)
.

Comment: That works, though with the call `sequelize.define('agent',{},{freezeTableName:true,tableName: 'agent'});` I'm now getting an error `column "updatedAt" of relation "agent" does not exist`.

Comment: Is that you created your table yourself or you ran generate and migration command? It may occur if migration wasn't done properly. More can be found in Sequelize cli documents

Comment: I created the table myself.  I haven't run any generate and migration command.

Comment: updatedAt, createdAt are additional columns created when you run sequelize generate and migration, in addition to that it creates an additional table in your current database which stores meta data. Now that you have created table by yourself it may not have these columns which it tries to fetch orelse update by default. I'll suggest you to create tables with generate and migrate command for smoother implementation.