# Strict Collection/Table name setting in Moleculer DBService

Tags: moleculer

I'm designing [Moleculer JS](https://github.com/moleculerjs) microservice which extends [Moleculer DB](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-db/tree/master/packages/moleculer-db) and can extend both SQL (for example [Sequelize](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-db/tree/master/packages/moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize)) and noSQL (for instance, [MongoDB](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-db/tree/master/packages/moleculer-db-adapter-mongo)) adapters.

Here is a `book` service schema

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const DBService = require('moleculer-db')

const pkg = require('../package.json')
const adapter = require('../db/sql.adapter')

module.exports = {
  name: 'book',
  version: pkg.version,
  mixins: [DBService],
  settings: {
    $noVersionPrefix: true,
    idField: 'id',
  },
  adapter,
  model: {
    name: 'book',
    define: {
      id: { type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, defaultValue: uuid },
      name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
  },
}
```

Though model name is `book` on moleculer service starting `books` table/collection will be created (it doesn't matter whether it is SQL or noSQL one). That is OK.

But in case I want to create another service which would keep deleted items, say `books_archive` or `book_archive` - `books_archives` or `book_archives` (respectively) will be created.

Sequelize [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#configuration) contains

```
freezeTableName: true,
tableName: 'booksArchive',
```

configuration properties, which I tried to put in `settings` block of the schema and inside `model` block, and inside adapter construction properties (see below) but with no luck - collection(table) created still just contains an extra `s` character. Is there any solution?

```
const adapter = new SQLAdapter(config.get('database.pg.uri'), {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'booksArchive',
})
```

Comment: This answer was useful for me in context of Sequelize adapter https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558832/1902296

Answer (score 0):

Based on sequelize docs, you should set them in Model options. Try it:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'book',
  version: pkg.version,
  mixins: [DBService],
  settings: {
    $noVersionPrefix: true,
    idField: 'id',
  },
  adapter,
  model: {
    name: 'book',
    define: {
      id: { type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, defaultValue: uuid },
      name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    options: {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'booksArchive',
    }
  },
}
```