# Table does not exist Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I created a customer model, then [this is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzg12.png)

then i tried to insert data into it [sequelize command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnvOa.png)

after i sent the post request to add the data here is what I got [sequelize error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8HT9.png)
the name of the model and table is customer (singular) but sequelize is looking for customers (plural).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is if you want singular table name other than auto generated plural name, you should update Sequelize configuration.

You can checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114499/how-to-make-sequelize-use-singular-table-names) and its answer.